# Choosing from multiple query results to display in a single form

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a form that submits parameters to a query, then opens the resulting record in another form. The problem is, whenever there is more than one record it automatically puts the first one into the from without any kind of option to choose the record I want. I have a macro set up on the search button on the first form that submits the parameters to the query and then displays it in the second form, I've tried to set up another macro in between the two, but I don't know if it's possible to set up the expression creator to check the number of rows resulting from a query. Is it possible to modify the query to create a prompt to choose which record I want? Or should I change something else?

This is the query:(automatically created by access)

```
SELECT CHILD.CHILD_L_NAME, CHILD.CHILD_F_NAME, CHILD.DOB, CHILD.GENDER, CHILD.DAYS_IN_CARE,
  CHILD.HOURS_PER_DAY, CHILD.ENROLLMENT_DATE, CHILD.CHILD_ADDRESS, CHILD.CHILD_CITY, 
  CHILD.CHILD_ZIP, CHILD.CHILD_STATE, CHILD.CLASSROOM, CHILD.SNACK, CHILD.LAST_UPDATED, CHILD.CIN
FROM CHILD
WHERE (((CHILD.CHILD_L_NAME)=[Forms]![Search]![L_NAME]) AND 
  ((CHILD.CHILD_F_NAME)=[Forms]![Search]![F_NAME])) OR 
  (((CHILD.CHILD_L_NAME)=[Forms]![Search]![L_NAME]) AND 
  ((CHILD.DOB)=[Forms]![Search]![DOB])) OR 
  (((CHILD.DOB)=[Forms]![Search]![DOB])) OR 
  (((CHILD.CHILD_L_NAME)=[Forms]![Search]![L_NAME]));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your problem and you use VBA it's quite easy to do.

You can create a reduced query based on the query you're creating with the button. This new query should include all and only the fields that allows you to discriminate beetwen the records to show in the 2nd form.

For instance it could include LastName, FirstName and classroom to select between children with same full name.

You can count the number of records of this 2nd query and if greater than 1 it means that you have more than one children to show.

So you can use this 2nd query to populate a combo-box or a listbox for selecting the record you really want to show.

When number of records is 1 you can simply skip the listbox population using an if statement on recordcount.

Next step is opening the form with the selected (or unique) record.

Bye